# Javascript check for empty fields, secure?

Tags: javascript, php

This is a simple question.
I have a registration form made with html and PHP. I want it to update while a person enters his information. When a person then enters his name, it uses javascript to check if the box is empty or not. If it is not empty, you can proceed, else you get a message saying that you have to enter some data into the field.

My question is, is this a secure way to check if the person has entered anything? Or should it be serverside with PHP so that I can be sure no empty information will be entered into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be both, really. Server-side validation is an absolute necessity. Client-side validation that compliments the server-side validation is good practice from a user-experience perspective.

It’s a good idea to have a look at some of the more popular PHP frameworks to see how they approach this problem. Validation rules are often kept in a model. For example, user authentication in Kohana 3.3 looks like this:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');

class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

  public function rules() {
    return array(
      'username' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
        array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
        array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')),
      ),
      'password' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
      ),
      'email' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
        array('email'),
        array(array($this, 'unique'), array('email', ':value')),
      ),
      'first_name' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
      ),
      'last_name' => array(
        array('not_empty'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never use javascript as the only check in your scripts. At least one check need to be serverside in PHP. Javascript can be manipulated because it's client side only and so be skipped.